# Using http.put() results in: '400 Bad Request for URL exception'

Tags: angular, angular-http

```
update(url: string, data: Object): Promise<Application> {
    return this.http
        .put(url, JSON.stringify(data), {headers: this.headers})
        .toPromise()
        .then(() => data)
        .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

Using the above function with a valid URL results in the following exception:

```
EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Response with status: 400 Bad Request for URL: null
```

I am using the `@angular/http` module to perform the request.
The strange thing about this problem is that other methods of the module work fine (`GET`, `POST` and `DELETE`).

I am using the following header `'Content-Type': 'application/json'` and the `InMemoryWebApiModule` to mock a response.

Calling the put function with a hard-coded value such as the following example results in the same exception.

```
this.http
        .put('app/applications/1', JSON.stringify(data), {headers: this.headers})
        .toPromise()
        .then(() => data)
        .catch(this.handleError);
```

Comment: Isnt' this all you need to know: "for URL: null" ?

Comment: Are you sure `update()` is called with an actual `url` value?

Comment: Yes, hardcoding a URL in the function results in the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem recently. The reason for this was that my data hadn't field named **id**, which uniquely identify each item. The module *@angular/http* matches requested data by its id.